# How to set the Current user_id in the Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-views

Alsomt all the answers are talking about how to set current user in the class with paraemter generics.ListCreateAPIView. But I'm just using APIView and I'm using function "post" to post the data.

Can someone tell me how can I set a current user_id in this file. And do I need to add something in the serializers.py too?

**views.py**

```
class CreateVideo(APIView):
    permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = VideoSerializer(data=request.data)
        user=self.request.user.id
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I created a variable "user" with self.request.user.id in it and then I passed it to the serializer.save(user). And when I created new video on the frontend side. It me gave a Bad Reuest Error.

Comment: *It me gave a Bad Reuest Error.* - What error did you get provide that?

Comment: please can you share VideoSerializer code

Comment: I think user attribute in `save()` method accepts user instance not user's id try to remove `.id` after `user`

Comment: I got Bad Request error in the terminal, because the user field is empty.

Comment: i think problem in VideoSerializer. Because `user` in `serializer.save(user)` not have any effect. If Video model have user field required, its raise error

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: it didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

You need Pass `request.user` instead of `self.request.user`.

-make sure user logged in or not ??

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = VideoSerializer(data=request.data)
        user=request.user
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Res
```

ponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)